# Calculate Geometry for Area is 0 in Arcmap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, field-calculator

I had a Nation wide data set was in WGS 1984, and then used the project tool  to NAD 1927 Contiguous USA Albers so that I could use the calculate geometry tool in the attribute table to get the Area in square miles, but when I do, I just get 0's when using the new projected file. It isn't disabled, but it is just giving 0 for outputs.

[image: Area_Final is my output]
[image: Calculate Geometry]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  Please [edit] your question to include details about how you projected your dataset and how you calculated geometry.  Include the steps involved, and some screenshots where appropriate to show your inputs.

Comment: can you provide some screen shots of the data you're working with

Comment: I have added additional screenshots and details.

Answer (score 2):

**Your features are too small to get a calculated Square Miles value.**

I'm not familiar with `NAD 1927 Contiguous USA Albers`, but I just chose that when creating a new feature class and it indicated the units are `Meters`.

[image]

Looking at your attribute table at the `SHAPE.LENGTH` and `SHAPE.AREA` fields, it appears you have very very small features, less than `1m` in length and less than `1 Sq. Meter` in area.

`1 Sq. Mile = 2589988.11 Sq. Meters`, so trying to calculate `Sq. Miles` from these will produce a very very small number, and to store it in the field it may just round the value to `0`.

To test, I created a polygon layer using `NAD 1927 Contiguous USA Albers` and created three very small features with similar Length and Area to yours, and one very large feature.  I then created a `DOUBLE` type field and used Calculate Geometry set to Square Miles.

The result was the same as yours for the small features - `0`.  As expected, the large feature had a calculated value.

I also calculated Hectares (`10000 Sq. Meters`) and Acres (`4046.86 Sq. Meters`) and did get a result albeit very small numbers.

[image]

Comment: If the data was not projected, could you use the area that was calculated using the Calculate geometry for a Feature Class still in GCS?